Is there any additional content in Help Wanted 2’s flat mode?
In December 2023, Five Nights at Freddy’s: Help Wanted 2 was released.  This game required the use of a VR headset.*
June 2024 saw the release of a flat version of the same game, so it can be played without a headset.
Is there any content in the flat version that isn’t in the VR version?
When the preceding game (Five Nights at Freddy's VR: Help Wanted) got updated to include a flat mode, it was also given some Easter eggs that weren’t in its original release.  For example, a way to go out through the Pizzeria’s “Employees Only” door was added, where you can see a “Coming Soon” billboard and the Pizzaplex under construction in the distance — this’s what’s prompting my question.
(There was also a Halloween-themed DLC mode: Curse of Dreadbear, but that’s not what I’m talking about.)

* The Mystic Hippo fortune teller minigame actually requires a particular headset (the PSVR2) because it involves eye-tracking.  This obviously isn’t at all possible in flat mode.  Fortunately though, this minigame is rather trivial and meaningless.

There is no additional content exclusive to the flat version of FNaF: Help Wanted 2.
But there was another update…

In December 2024, an update to Help Wanted 2 was released that shows some glimpses of the upcoming title: FNaF: Secret of the Mimic (2025).
There’s a new button on the Mystic Hippo fortune teller machine.  This activates some new cryptic clues for what to do next.

If you go to the hinted-at minigame and enter the right code, you’ll receive a plush:

 

 This resembles the Tiger Rock character from Tales from the Pizzaplex: Tiger Rock, and is related to (Edwin Murray’s son) David’s toy from Tales from the Pizzaplex: The Mimic.


Another clue from the hippopotamus reveals this stage figure:

 

 This is the Mimic wearing the decrepit lion costume from the scooper ending of FNaF: Security Breach — RUIN.


Following the psychic’s suggestions once more leads us to a room with Jackie’s box from the Secret of the Mimic — Teaser Debut.
An unsolved puzzle appears.
With the update, there’s a dozen or so puzzle pieces that can be found throughout the various existing minigames.

Completing the puzzle with the security mask on…

 … transports you to the outside of a building:

 

 This appears to be the abandoned lace factory that became Edwin Murray’s.


Looking at the puzzle with the VANNI mask off…

 … reveals a van with the MXES security system in the back.  After entering a code, we briefly see the Entity (from RUIN), before the van closes and promptly drives away.

 





